# Installing gevent on Windows with Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, windows, gevent

I'm having trouble installing gevent on my Windows 8.1 machine (Python 2.7.9).

When I run `pip install gevent` I get an error that ends with

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsall
raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

[Full log (pip.log)](http://pastebin.com/DG7pv2zK)

I've also installed Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition as suggested by some other forums I found but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2.7 you need to get [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://aka.ms/vcpython27). That is the *only* [supported compiler today for 2.7](http://pycon.blogspot.ro/2015/03/for-microsoft-python-support-extends.html). It's a special package made by Microsoft that has all the stuff necessary for Python 2.7. It is supported since setuptools 6.0 (eg: run `pip install "setuptools>=6.0"`).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by

1. Installing Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 32-bit
2. Executing `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS110COMNTOOLS%` in the CMD
3. [Doing the 2 first steps here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s.aspx)

Comment: Consider implementing the answer from @ionelmc instead. It's better for the extension module to link with the CRT that python27.dll uses, i.e. msvcr90.dll. Using multiple CRTs in a process can lead to problems managing resources such as allocated memory and open files.